# How to use form fields in Wordpress to make calculations and display the results in a table?

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, html-table, calculated-field

I'm quite a beginner, and I've been trying to make a form on Wordpress that would enable me to make calculations with the customer inputs, and then display the results in a table (rather in a new page).

I'm well aware that there a plenty of plugins on wp, and I've been using HTML forms plugin.

The thing is, I have my HTML form ready, and the plugin allows me to send the inputs by e-mail (which is already cool), but I have no idea of how to use those inputs, define variables that are dependent on those inputs, and to display them in a table..

Here is part of my HTML form  :

```
<div class="slidecontainer">       
<p>Fluid temperature (in ° C) :</p>
<input type="range" min="0" max="2000" value="200" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p>Temperature : <span id="demo" </span></p>
</div>

<div id="flow"> 
<label for="number">Fluid flow</label>
<input type="number" name="flow">
<select><p>select a unit:</p>
<option value="Nm^3">Nm^3</option>
<option value="kg/s">Kg/s</option>
</select>
</div>  

<div id="running time"> 
<label for="number">Running time</label>
<input type="number" name="running time" min="0" max="8784"> 
<span>hours/year</span>
</div>

<div id="fluid purity">
<label for="text">Fluid purity</label>
<input type="radio" name="purity" value="0">0</input>
<input type="radio" name="purity" value="1">1</input>
<input type="radio" name="purity" value="2">2</input>
<input type="radio" name="purity" value="3">3</input>
<input type="radio" name="purity" value="4">4</input>
<input type="radio" name="purity" value="5">5</input>
</div>
```

Basically, I would like to display variables that depend on those inputs.

For example :

```
Let T be the input fluid temperature 
Let F be the input flow of the fluid  
Let Rt be the input running time in hours
Let P be the input fluid purity (with 0 ≤ P ≤ 5)
```

I would like to set the following variables:

```
Y (Yield) = 17% if T≤300°C
Y = 0.1*T - 13 if 300° ≤ T ≤ 350°
Y =22% if T>350°

Then an intermediate variable T(out)=20*P + 120
and Δ(T) = T – T(out) 

that helps calculate the Thermal Power TPw
TPw = 0,00042 * Δ(T) * F if  the input unit chosen is Nm^3/h 
TPw= 0,00042 * (1/1,3)* F * Δ(T) * 3,6 * 10-6 if kg/s unit chosen
```

... That is just part of what I have to do but I have no idea of how to display those variables Y and TPw in a table after submiting my form :(

Would anyone have a clue ?